# Magento 2: I need to call same class method in static function

Tags: magento2

I need to call same class method in same Class static function. Is it possible.

Any idea please share.

```
public function getMake()
{
  // sample
}
static public function getMaker()
{
   // call getMake() function here

}
```

Comment: CANNOT do that.

Answer (score 0):

To call an non-static function you need an instantiated object of the class or access to $this in the function which is not the case in a static function.

I don't know what your classes returns or do but it is possible to call the non-static function by passing an object of the class into the static function like so:

```
class Foo {

    private function bar () {
        echo "Hello World!";
    }

    static public function staticBar (Foo $foo) {
        return $foo -> bar ();
    }
}
```